# Python 2 timezone.utc in Django project

Tags: python, django

What is the alternative for Python 2 :

```
user_last_seen = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

Thank you

Comment: `datetime.utcnow()`? But the above should work in Python-2.x as well. Note that Python-2.x is no longer supported after january 1, 2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
import time

user_last_seen = time.gmtime()
print user_last_seen
```

More info on https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html